# Newton Raphson method in c++

Tags: function, pointers

I delcaration a newton function is

```
double newton(double x_lower, double x_upper, double accuracy, 
void (*f_pt)(double *f_value, double *f_derivative, double x));
```

The f_pt is a point to a function that calculates f(x) and f'(x)

I develop functions

```
double f(double x);
double f_D(double x);
```

How to write the part of `void (*f_pt)(double *f_value, double *f_derivative, double x)`